# How can obtain the pdf of y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a problem as follows:
$$Y_k=N_k+AS_K \quad ,k=1,\ldots,n.$$$$$$where $\underline{N} \sim N(\underline{0},I)$ and where $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, independent of $\underline{N}$ and each taking on the values $+1$ and $-1$ with equal probabilities of $\frac{1}{2}$. I want to obtain pdf of $\underline{Y}$ ? 
$A$ is constant value.
Can anyone help me! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries $Y_k$ of $\underline{Y}$ are i.i.d. If the density of each $N_k$ is $g$, the density of each $Y_k$ is the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=\frac12(g(x+A)+g(x-A))$.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use the independence condition. 
$$
P( Y_k \leq x ) = P( N_k + AS_k \leq x ) \\ = 
P( N_k + AS_k \leq x | S_k = -1 )P( S_k = -1 ) + P( N_k + AS_k \leq x | S_k = 1 )P( S_k = 1 ) = P( N_k - A \leq x | S_k = -1 )P( S_k = -1 ) + P( N_k + A \leq x | S_k = 1 )P( S_k = 1 ) 
= P( N_k - A \leq x )P( S_k = -1 ) + P( N_k + A \leq x )P( S_k = 1 ) \\
= P( N_k \leq x + A )P( S_k = -1 ) + P( N_k \leq x - A )P( S_k = 1 ) \\
= \frac{1}{2}( \int_{-\infty}^{x+A} f(t)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{x-A} f(t)dt \: ) \\
= \frac{1}{2}( \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t - A)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t+A)dt \: ) \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{f(t - A) + f(t + A)}{2} dt
$$

Comment: Try to avoid conflicting notations (too many $x$s).

Comment: I went ahead and changed the variable inside the integrals to 't', to avoid confusion with 'x'.

Comment: I just didn't notice that, thanks for the remark